# Validation of an xsd file with elements attributes and children

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write an XSD file with an element that has an attribute and three children. I get the following error message:

> The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (restriction | extension)).
>   adress_validator.xsd:18: element complexType: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, ((simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)).
>   WXS schema adress_validator.xsd failed to compile

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
 xmlns:tns="https://www.w3schools.com"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="adress_book">
       <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="house" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:simpleContent>-
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
               <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"
                 use="required"></xsd:attribute>
             </xsd:extension>
           </xsd:simpleContent>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="surname"></xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="first_name"></xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="phone_number"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
 </xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work for you? An element with three children and one attribute:

```
<element name="top">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="one" type="string"/>
        <element name="two" type="string"/>
        <element name="three" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
      <attribute name="something" type="string"/>
    </complexType>
</element>
```